# Get all variables within Umbraco custom data type

Tags: angularjs, variables, properties, umbraco

I've just started working with Umbraco and I could not find an answer to a simple issue I keep struggling with.

```
<div ng-controller="My.MovieLinker">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="model.visibility" /><br />
<input type="text" ng-if="model.visibility"  /><br />
<input type="text" ng-if="model.visibility"/><br />
<input type="text" ng-if="model.visibility" /><br />

<textarea ng-model="model.value"></textarea>
</div>
```

I've created this simple data type. The issue is I can only reference model.value but nothing else from my angular model. Is there a syntax with which I can reference model.visibility for instance?

Comment: Can you post the code for the controller as well please?

Comment: `angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("My.MovieLinker",
    function () {
    });`

This is the whole controller

Comment: I want to reference another value from Umbraco Template

I can reference the value with `@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("ML") `where ML is a property with my data type in it